# Google Directions Service w/ Waypoints returning ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I currently have a DirectionsRenderer function that properly routes To and From fields on my page. After the routing is done I grab the overview_path and then load elements from a Fusion Table based on the path. Once this is done I've set up a listener looking for 'directions_changed', which would indicate a waypoint as such:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function(){

        var wypnt = directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoints.toString().match(/[^()]+/);
        wypnt.toString().split(",");
        wypnt = new google.maps.LatLng(wypnt[1],wypnt[0]);

        var waypoint = [];

        waypoint.push({ location: wypnt, stopover: true });

        route(waypoint);
    });
```

Once I pass it back to the route() function (the function that works normally with the To and From fields), I have this section of code:

```
if(waypoint){

    var request = {
        origin: document.getElementById("search-input-from").value,
        destination: document.getElementById("search-input-to").value,
        waypoints: waypoint,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
}
else{

    var request = {
        origin: document.getElementById("search-input-from").value,
        destination: document.getElementById("search-input-to").value,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
}
```

The rest of the code is based off the following if statement:

```
directionService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

       //do stuff

     }
    else {
                alert("Directions query failed: " + status);
            }
    };
```

Unfortunately all I'm getting back is "Directions query failed: ZERO_RESULTS". Any idea why this is happening? I'm not sure if the way I'm forming the waypoint is wrong or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

```
    wypnt.toString().split(",");
```

this will not have any effect to wypnt, split will not modify the original object. it has to be:

```
     wypnt = wypnt.toString().split(",");
```

Why are you switching latitude and longitude here?

```
    wypnt = new google.maps.LatLng(wypnt[1],wypnt[0]);
```

it has to be

```
   wypnt = new google.maps.LatLng(wypnt[0],wypnt[1]);
```

Most of all: why do you do it at all? you take an array, convert it to a string, split the string to get the original array.

Simply use:

```
 google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', 
   function(){
   var waypoints=directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes[0]
                    .legs[0].via_waypoints||[];
    for(var i=0;i<waypoints.length;++i){
       waypoints[i]={stopover:true,location: waypoints[i]}
    }
    route(waypoints);
});
```

But note: when you redraw the route `directions_changed` will fire again.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the help. I believe the LatLng object switches where the Lat and Lng are, hence the switch between the [1] and [0].

And what I mean by that is Lng goes in first when building a LatLng object (at least I believe that to be the case).

Comment: Trying it this way I got

`Uncaught Error: Error in property <waypoints>: (Invalid value: (-31.0503894, 151.7545473) (Error in element at position 0: (Unknown property <mb>))) `

via_waypoints brings out the object displayed as "(Lat, Long)", where the LatLng object goes in as Long, Lat (no parentheses).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that waypoints are not simple LatLng's, see my edited answer.

Comment: Works! Thank you! Just before I let you go though, could you explain the "via_waypoints||[]" part? I've never seen that and I'm not sure what it's doing.

Comment: It will set waypoints to an empty array when via_waypoints is not set, to avoid errors with the for-loop(but it's redundant, via_waypoints will always be an array). Basically it's a shorthand for `var foo=(value==true)?value:alternativeValue;`

Comment: Ah that makes sense. You're right too, it seems `directions_changed` is firing a LOT. I'm getting OVER_QUERY_LIMIT and it's happening infinitely. Not sure how to get around that. Maybe set the listener out of the route function somewhere?